# How to say this in Chinese? (This contains 7 questions)

Tags: translation

1) To accidentally hurt yourself with something sharp like needle. For example : I accidentally pricked my finger with a needle (*please help me translate this* ㅠㅠ)

2) What are the correct translation for these levels of crying in Chinese? : whimpering, silent tears (or crying silently), sniveling, weeping, sobbing, blubbering

3) What's the term to say "to hold pee" in Chinese?

4) Also the translation of : "someone hacks your account" and "your photos/data are leaked"?

5) And what how do you say it in Chinese? : no matter..., for example to express something like this : no matter how busy I am, I don't think I'll be as busy as you are (I hope you can get the nuance since I can't think of any equal translation from my language to English)

6) Does Chinese differentiate between "to wish" and "to hope"? In English, "to wish" sounds more hypothetical. Is it the same in Chinese?

7) Last, how do you express "(Something) drives me crazy" and "I think I'll go crazy/I'm going to be crazy" in Chinese?

*Thank you so much for anyone who helps me with this!!! Forgive me if this question is too long and if most of them are trivial/stupid questions >_<*

Comment: Thanks for anyone who helped me edit this question. BUT... Instead of downvoting my question, why don't you help me answer them? ㅠㅠㅠㅠ

Comment: This is not a question, this is 7 questions. Also, you need to show your attempt at all of the questions.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion to show my attempt but the thing is, I have looked for answers. Sure, I found the answers for half of my questions but I'm not sure whether or not they are correct. Plus, I can only post a question every 30 minutes or something. If I knew they were all correct, I wouldn't be asking about them here.

Comment: see dictionaries: e.g. iciba,bkrs: accidentally 偶然地，意外地，非故意地；I pricked my finger with a needle.我的手指叫针给扎了一下,whimper,sob 啜泣，呜咽,silent tears 无声的泪水,snivel,blubber 哭诉,weep 哭泣； 流泪,hold pee (keep one's urine)保持小便,hack account 黑客帐户,information leak 信息泄露,there is/has been a leak 走漏了风声,photos 照片，相片,data 数据,(materials)资料，材料,no matter how, even if  不管如何； 哪怕； wish  希望； 想要； 祝愿； hope 希望，期望；see examples,drive crazy  使受不了； 将...逼得发疯； go crazy 发疯,see examples also at bkrs,e.g.泄露机密、秘密、天机、原子机密

Comment: asking for bulk translation, meaningless title. This question should be deleted

Comment: Firstly, I never knew that some people in Stack Exchange community are like this. Taking one freaking question (okay, one question that contains 6 other questions) so personally. It's just questions. If you have problem with this (which I can't relate why) or if you don't like how I wrote this, just.leave.it. Seriously, you can just leave it. I don't force you to answer this. Secondly, I have explained as why I asked those 7 questions all at once (if you read my explanation tho).

Comment: Next, even the one who helped me answer those 7 questions didn't say something like you did. You don't help at all, yet you still have the audacity to say things like "meaningless title, this question should be deleted". Wow.

Comment: Lastly, I'm new to this community. I guess instead of complaining about my questions, you should have guided me on how to ask questions properly here. God, I still can't believe that you all take this question so seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) To accidentally hurt yourself with something sharp like needle. For example : I accidentally pricked my finger with a needle

不小心 (accidentally) 扎傷了 (punctured and injured)

我不小心被針扎傷了 (I accidentally pricked my finger with a needle)

> 2) What are the correct translation for these levels of crying in Chinese? : whimpering, silent tears (or crying silently), sniveling, weeping, sobbing, blubbering

whimpering = 嗚咽

silent tears = 潛然淚下

sniveling = 哭哭啼啼

weeping = 飲泣

sobbing = 抽泣

blubbering = 哭哭啼啼

> 3) What's the term to say "to hold pee" in Chinese?

忍尿

> 4) Also the translation of : "someone hacks your account" and "your photos/data are leaked"?

"有人侵入你的帳戶" "你的照片/數據被洩露了"

> 5) And what how do you say it in Chinese? : no matter..., for example to express something like this : no matter how busy I am, I don't think I'll be as busy as you are (I hope you can get the nuance since I can't think of any equal translation from my language to English)

No matter = 不管/ 無論

> 6) Does Chinese differentiate between "to wish" and "to hope"? In English, "to wish" sounds more hypothetical. Is it the same in Chinese?

wish = 願 (wish for something you desired )

hope = 望 (hope for something to happen the way you wanted)

> 7) Last, how do you express "(Something) drives me crazy" and "I think I'll go crazy/I'm going to be crazy" in Chinese?

(Something) drives me crazy = (Something) 讓我發狂

I'm going to be crazy =  我快要發狂了

Comment: your post is very long, I can only give brief, direct answers. If you ask one question at a time, I can explain more and provide some examples

Comment: Thank you so much. So sad that you couldn't provide the details of each of my questions because there's a limit to your answer (I just knew about it, tbh) but it's all right. Guess I can ask for the details later. It was all because I was in a rush. Besides, I can only post a question every 30/40 minutes. So it'll take hours to look for the answers. Once again, thank you for helping me out ^_^

Comment: There's no limit to the length of my answer, I just don't want the post to be too long